# Order of Operations Simple Brain Teaser

Tags: c#, operator-precedence

I have a simple piece of code that doesn't do what I expect. What is wrong with this code?

```
int value1 = (int).5*100;
```

This is pretty easy but through me for a loop for a good moment. Of course, the answer is trivial and already known.  But, I thought it might be fun for someone to think about.

Credit will be given to first person who come up with the correct solution and explains why.

Comment: `I have a simple piece of code that doesn't do what I expect`. Well, if you expected it to make coffee, you'll have to plug the coffee-brewing subroutine or it'll never work.

Comment: @KooKiz Don't forget the syntactic sugar!

Comment: Besides the coffee: Isn't that spam?

Answer (score 16):

"what is wrong": the insufficient use of parenthesis, forcing me to memorise and recite stupid precedence rules (which are intended to satisfy compilers, not human eyes), making it hard to write and even harder to maintain.

If the meaning is *even a little bit* in doubt, add parenthesis. Even if they aren't needed. Then this is a non-issue. And you don't have to memorise anything!

If the code was written as either:

```
((int)0.5)*100
```

or:

```
(int)(0.5*100)
```

Then I doubt the question would ever be necessary :)

Comment: +1 for "intended to satisfy compilers, not human eyes". I never want to have to think about precedence rules when reading someone's code. **Ever**.

Answer (score 10):

Firsty it casts `.5` to `int`, which results in `0`, then it multiplies it by `100` which results in ( 0 * 100 ) `0`.

If you expect it to be `50` then you need to use parenthesis (so multiplication goes first, then type cast):

```
int value1 = (int)(.5*100);
```

It is always better to put more parenthesis than less, it costs nothing and it increases readability and understanding.

MSDN Library: [Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the precedence of the cast, the cast has an higher precedence so i gets executed before the multiplication operation, you have to use parenthesis to alter the precedence, try in this way :

```
int value1 = (int)(.5 * 100);
```